# Xamarin.Forms implement Calender for all platforms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a question im new to Xamarin.Forms
and trying to add a item into my event (Calendar) but i dont know how to do it 
in Android studio its very simple using EKEvent but in Xamarin forms i have no clue.

Comment: Note, that using xamarin forms to do that, you would need to either find c cross platform implementation or create your own (using dependency services).  You can also have a look here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39954/how-to-access-calendar-from-xamarin-forms

Comment: Already looked there but thats not what i want

Comment: You most likely need to write a platform specific calendar class and use DependencyService to make it available to XF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with DependencyService Thnx guys :)
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/